# Is using email hash as user id a good solution to ensure anonymity?

Tags: security, hash, string-hashing, anonymity

Imagine you want to create a "secure" messaging app which must comply to:

If someone has access to server databases, he/she can not identify the user from the field your using to substitute the normal username / email.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072263/anonymizing-users-in-django) solution seems interesting.

But I wonder:

- If there are any better (more secure) alternatives
- What hashing mechanism one should use

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  Hashes are good for hiding secret information, like passwords.  For information like email addresses, which are usually quite easily guessed/googled, an attacker could easily pre-generate a huge list of hashes for a database of email addresses and quickly use a reverse lookup to find out if a given hash (on your system) matches up with one of the addresses in the database.  That's putting aside the fact that hashes are not unique, which probably isn't a problem with a big enough hash address space.

Generally, if you want anonymous IDs, you should use randomly generated ones.

Comment: However, using a random IDs may be become totally impractical if think of use case of native mobile messaging app: user A may know user B's email, but it doesn't have access to its random ID... I wonder if using a combination of email hash + salt + secret would do the trick of getting anonymity without sacrificing implementability.